# Jython and the ArcGIS Java SDK

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

Is it possible, or would it be feasible to use a [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) environment to interact with this the [ArcObjects SDK for Java](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/concepts/engine/)? 
Or would it be better overall to [learn](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-java) the native language of the API? 
Additionally, do any immediate limitations come to mind?

My desire to explore this API rests with a familiarity in Python, and a few experiences where ArcPy had not yet exposed the [functionality](https://darrenwiens.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/using-arcobjects-in-python/) I needed. The scope for my use of the API is meant only to resolve minor ArcPy limitations at this time.

I am looking for any information, tutorials, or anecdotal experience on leveraging a Jython interpreter to use ArcObjects SDK for Java functionality.

EDIT: In the original post I failed to make the distinction between the [ArcObjects SDK for Java](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/concepts/engine/) and the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/). For this question I'm interested in the ArcObjects SDK specifically in terms of calling ArcObjects functionality from Jython. Alas, after some months and additional, related questions here on [GISSE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163329/ironpython-and-the-arcgis-net-sdk) and [another board](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/172282) the consensus has been to just cowboy up, take off the training wheels and learn to access ArcObjects for .NET via C#. Every language, framework etc. has its limitations and benefits. In the ArcGIS environment and for my particular situation, effectively [forcing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes) Python to expose ArcObjects feels like it amounts to more effort than would be necessary just using the .NET option.

If in the future anyone does attempt handling of ArcObjects (Java SDK) via Jython, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Comment: Officious and heavy handed moderation - seems like a reasonable question to me. Is PolyGeo paid to put people's posts on hold, or is just a hobby? Is it a power thing, do you think?

Comment: I don't know PolyGeo personally or very well at all, but I do know he/she moderates a lot of posts, so the decisions laid out here could just be a matter of reflex or policy, I'm thinking. Thanks for your support and also thanks PolyGeo for highlighting a need to be more specific.